# Plot user location onto line map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, coordinates, mkoverlay

Ok, I've done some reading around the subject, have an idea of how I'd tackle my problem, but want to find out of this is the most efficient way, or if I'm missing something simple.

I have a line diagram of a section of railway that I'd like to plot the users location onto (the user being someone on a train moving up/down the railway).

Now, I initially went down the route of geo-referencing, but quickly realised this probably wasn't the way to go, as my image is not a real reflection of the area + I want the line diagram to be what the user sees.

OK, my though process of how I will tackle it:

1. I know the physical area so I could extract the coordinates along the railway, every x meters (my line diagram has a resolution of around 5m). Stick this into an array. Can anyone suggest a tool to do this?!
2. Allocate my line diagram a start and end, then match the image coordinates with the physical coordinates for the entire line.
3. Read in the users position and update where to draw the position based on the closest match in the array?

Does this sound doable, and would it give me decent results?

If you have more sophisticated answers, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds reasonable in general. As the user is supposed to be on a train a simpler option may work where you just keep track of the physical distance moved and use that as a percentage distance along the line. This is a lot simpler to manage and could be backed up with some coordinate checkpoints to ensure you don't have a drifting error. I'd aim for a simpler implementation if you can.